# mysql query optimization with order by and limit by clause

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, pagination

I have one table that contains member's audit information.

I have a query like:

```sql
select columnsname from tablename 
where member id =? 
order by audit_date desc, audit_time desc 
limit 0,150
```

This query is taking a long time to execute. The table I'm querying contains around 2 to 3 billion records.

I can't remove the order by clause as I want records in descending order of audit date and audit time. I also can't remove limit by clause because I need pagination functionality.

I have already applied an index on member id, audit_date and audit_time.

Can any one help me to optimize this query or suggest any other approach that I can apply in the Java tier to achieve this functionality?

Below is my explain output.
Left side is column name and right side is the value of it.

```
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┐
│ Column Name   │ Column Value                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│ ID            │ 1                                │
│ Select Type   │ simple                           │
│ table         │ member_audit_info                │
│ type          │ ref                              │
│ possible_keys │ member_audit_info_memebrid_index │
│ key           │ member_audit_info_memebrid_index │
│ ref           │ const                            │
│ rows          │ 208988                           │
│ extra         │ Using where,Using filesort       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: please, if you can, show table structure.

Comment: Please also add the output of `explain select column_name from ...`

Comment: yes i can but actually I am very new on stackoverflow so i don't know how to add post in tabular form.please can you help me in this also?

Comment: edit your question and add your output like code.

Comment: Do you have indexes on audit_date and audit_time?

Comment: Yes audit_date and audit_time has already index

Comment: I tried to infer the proper column names from the line above the table but I'm not sure about "Column Value", if it's not correct please edit it and correct it.

Comment: it is correct information.Please can you tell me exact about the doubt of Column Value

Comment: Is the information in that table representative of *one row of data*, or is it supposed to be the table structure that @disable1992 requested? If it was supposed to be the table structure, I would have expected to see datatypes.

Comment: No actually it is explain plan of my query.

Answer (score 0):

Use single column `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` that contains both date and time parts and sort based on that **single column**, that might improve the performance of the query.

Sample query:

```
select columnsname from tablename 
where member_id =? 
order by audit_timestamp desc 
limit 0,150
```

**Note:**(*few more points on the performance of the query*)

- column `member id` should be indexed.
- fetch only required columns
- **reduce the limit** (pagination size)

Comment: Thanks for your nice suggestion.but this table structure has already applied in production and it's alsmost impossible that we can change the table structure.We are fetching only required columns and memebr_id is already indexed.

Comment: Try last option after reducing the limit (pagination size) that might help in performance.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.and i have also one idea.if i will make a temporary view with query select columnsname from tablename 
where member_id =? and audit_date between <startdate> and <enddate> and then fire a query on this view with order by clause and limit clause.so is it a better option or this can give performance isuue

Comment: create a new view from the actual table that combines audit_date and audit_time in a single column (timestamp) then fire your all queries on this view and that will definitely improve the performance.